# UnboundLocalError- local variable 'term_list' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

In my Django view I am building a list I want to  read in my template 
my list name is `term_list` and I append to it inside for loop

```
def lease_payment_details(request, pk): 
    lease_id = pk

    if lease_id:
        try:
            lease = get_object_or_404(Lease, pk=lease_id)
            try:
                activeterm = LeaseTerm.objects.get(lease=lease)
                start = activeterm.start_period.order_value
                end = activeterm.end_period.order_value

                period_list = Period.objects.filter(order_value__lte = start, order_value__gte = end)
                total = 1000
                for obj in period_list:
                    obj.discount = 0
                    obj.amount = activeterm.amount
                    obj.topay = total - obj.amount - obj.discount
                    term_list.append(obj)



                payment = activeterm.leasepayment_set.all().order_by('payment_date')
            except LeaseTerm.DoesNotExist:
                activeterm = None
                payment = None


        except ValueError:

            raise Http404get_object_or_404(Lease, pk=lease_id)
    else:

        lease = "None"
        activeterm = "None"
        payment = "None"
        term_list = "None"

    data = {
            'lease': lease, 'payment': payment, 'activeterm':activeterm,'term_list':term_list, 
            }

    return render(request, 'lease/lease_payment_details.html', {'data': data})
```

but  I am getting this error

> local variable 'term_list' referenced before assignment

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't defined it. Add `term_list = []` to the beginning of your code.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks

Comment: Also, you can't _build_ a tuple as tuples are immutable. There is no `append` method for tuples.

Comment: that means I am building  list.Updated my question. thanks

Comment: If you Initialize some variables , put it on before the conditions so it will be good approch

Answer (score 0):

Before you can execute `term_list.append(obj)`, you must declare term_list as a list with `term_list = list()` or `term_list = []`.